# Imparted vs Imputed

Tags: vocabulary, language-evolution

so I am a bit confused by the meaning of the two words: imparted and imputed. 
I know impart means to give or to communicate something. Impute means to ascribe. However, I dont know how can i diffrentiate between their usage in scentences. (I have a quiz comming up, and most vocabulary questions comes as fill in the blanks.)
So when can I use which?
I also have a scentence and I want to make sure it is correct:
 His friends imputed his silence to being unfriendly because of the behavior he imparted towards them.

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: The statement *X imputes Y to Z* would normally imply the speaker (or ***X***, if that's a person with an opinion, rather than a *reason* for the assessment) believes ***Z*** (already) has the quality ***Y***, but that this isn't generally known. On the other hand, *X imparts Y to Z* would normally imply that ***Z*** only has quality ***Y*** because of ***X***. In short, a *person* or an *argument, justification* would normally "impute" a value judgement (that was always "true"), whereas an *active cause* normally "imparts" an actual quality to its subject (which it didn't have before).

Comment: (...in your example context, I don't really see how *his friends **imparted...** his silence* could ever make sense, but it's a bit unclear whether he ***imparted*** or ***imputed*** behaviour to his friends.)

Comment: I'm with @FumbleFingers on this one, I've always used imparted in the sense of "give" like a grandfather imparts his wisdom of fly fishing techniques to his grandson... and imputed to have a sense of "ascribe", as in your example about a value judgement

Comment: @cmcf: Indeed. In your example, if the grandfather *imputed* his wisdom to his grandson, it would be a bit weird. But I'd probably be forced to assume it meant the grandfather was saying that in some way he *acquired wisdom from the grandson* (perhaps indirectly, from activities that only came about because of his grandson), rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of "imputed" is correct, but the phrasing is odd for the "imparted". I would definitely say something else like the "behavior he showed [them]" or "behavior he demonstrated"

Or just replace "imparted toward" with "imparted to". It is still odd, because it implies that somehow his friends adopted his behavior.

But if this is a fill-in question where you must choose from only "imparted" and "imputed", you chose wisely—despite the awkward construction of the sentence, which is the testmaker's fault, not yours.